# $A$-invariant subspaces $\operatorname{Gr}(k)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in GL(d,\mathbb{R})$, which is the space of $d\times d$ invertible matrices. Assume that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is irreducible over  $Q$. I want to find $A$-invariant subspaces $\operatorname{Gr}(k)$, which is a Grassmannian of $k$-planes of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

My attempt: I think one needs to find the eigenspaces $\wedge^{k} A$ that are $A$-invariant subspaces $\operatorname{Gr}(k)$. If the previous sentence is correct, I have the following problems:$A$-invariant subspaces $\operatorname{Gr}(k)$ are $k$-dimensional, but the eigenspaces $\wedge^{k} A$ are $\binom nk$-dimensional.

Comment: This is determined by $A$'s real canonical form, although how precisely seems tricky. WLOG, the linear operator is multiplication by $T$ on a direct sum of modules of the form $\mathbb{R}[T]/\pi(T)^n$ where $\pi$ is linear or irreducible quadratic. Invariant subspaces are not simply sums of these summands though - for instance isoclinic rotations have infinitely many invariant subspaces.

Comment: @runway44 :  Thanks for your comment. Assume that the characteristic polynomial is irreducible over  $Q$. Then, can we consider the eigenspaces of the exterior products? If not, under what assumptions we can consider it?

Comment: If the char poly is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ then there are no repeated roots. If the char poly has no repeated roots, then (ignoring dimensions) the $A$-invariant subspaces are precisely the direct sums of the minimal ones, and there are finitely many minimal ones (you get a minimal one, in this case, by summing a conjugate pair of eigenspaces in $\Bbb C^n$ and then intersecting with $\Bbb R^n$).

Comment: @runway44 : Thanks for your comment again. Sorry, I don't understand what you meant by "the minimal ones"? what do you mean by summing a conjugate pair?ou meant Invariant subspaces are simply sums of the summands?If not, do you know under what assumptions we have it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A minimal invariant subspace, as you might expect, is a proper nontrivial invariant subspace that does not contain any smaller nontrivial invariant subspaces. Extend the action of $A$ from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb C^n$, and let $V_\lambda$ be a nontrivial eigenspace for a complex number $\lambda$. Then $V_{\overline{\lambda}}$ is also a nontrivial eigenspace, where $\overline{\lambda}$ is the conjugate, and $(V_\lambda\oplus V_{\overline{\lambda}})\cap\Bbb R^n$ is a minimal invariant subspace of $\Bbb R^n$, and this is how all of them arise.

Comment: Indeed, all the minimal invariant subspaces (again, assuming the char poly is separable) will be 1D or 2D, and in the latter case $A$ will act as a similarity transformation (rotation + dilation). Every other invariant subspace will be a combination of these. If the char poly isn't separable, things get much trickier.

Comment: @runway44  : Thank you very much.